# Filters Raw value in Views on multilingual site?

Tags: drupal-views, multilingual, drupal-8

On Drupal8, I have a View who filter nodes from 2 parameters (each is a Taxonomy ID from different vocabulary). So I have a path like `/filter1/%/filter2/%` where `filter1` raw value is the path component 2 `filter2` raw value is the path component 4.

It works fine on the default language on the site cause there's no langcode in the url. But when I switch to a different language the langcode is added to the path and it becomes `/zh-hans/filter1/%/filter2/%` or `/fr/filter1/%/filter2/%`.

At this point the view is not working correctly anymore cause `filter1` raw value is the path component 3 and `filter2` raw value is the path component 5.

Anybody knows how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working around I find out that my question was dumb. The view didn't worked in chinese but it was not about the thing I mentionned. I take a look to the condition with a hook_views_query_alter and saw that the arguments where retrieved correctly in the url whatever language the page is in...

My problem was a I put a filter criteria on "Content: Translation language (= Interface text language selected for page)". I usually use it to display the result in the correct language. But in this case, it avoid results to display on other language than the default one. I don't understand why but it works without it and it serves the right translated nodes.